# verify placeholder text in a web page using selenide with java

Tags: java, web, selenide

using selenide and java need to validate/assert placeholder text on a field is displayed/exists.
The HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Your amount value (1 to 100)" maxlength="20" name="money" type="tel" value="$0">
```

I know how to do it in selenium.But I am looking for a solution using selenide.

```java
String password=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ur css path")).getAttribute("placeholder");
```

I need to validate that placeholder is present on this specific field.

Answer (score 0):

you can check placeholder Attribute text:

```
 attribute("placeholder", "some text") // $(“#list li”).shouldHave(attribute(“placeholder”, “some text”))
```

or you can check placeholder be present by this way

```
attribute("placeholder") // e.g. $(“#input”).shouldHave(attribute(“placeholder”))
```